# Subdomain redirect to subdirectory

Tags: redirect, dns

I have a domain in which I want the subdirectory to be shown as a subdomain in the url.
I do not want it to be a subdomain because it'll cause problems with the integration of two cms's that I have.

I would like

```
forum.domain.com -> domain.com/forum
```

to redirect to there but I would also like it to keep saying forum.domain.com in the url and not change to /forum.

I do have access to the DNS zones but I am completely lost on how to do this. So far my forum.domain.com is a website by itself in which I do not want it to be.

*Server Htaccess is running helicon ape.

Comment: Ah hah, so you're using Windows for the web server. My best advice then is to *stop now*, and set up the site based on Linux (like Ubuntu). You'll spare yourself a lot of future time spent hunting Stack Overflow for answers. E.g., you're already going to have problems: Helicon Ape looks like a big hack, just to get the Microsoft web server to act like Apache, and be configurable.

Comment: I would but I am helping a friend out make a website but he hosted with a windows server. So there is nothing I can do about that tbh.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done purely through DNS. It's not hard, but it does involve your web server's configuration.

1. In DNS, create a CNAME (an alias) for forum.domain.com to point to your server, probably domain.com.
2. In your webserver's configuration, configure a new virtual host with that path as its document home. The way you do this will depend on whether you use Apache, Nginx, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks I think i get what needs to be done. problem is I am not sure if I have access to the webserver config through my host. I'll try to figure it out and post my findings here. Makes me hate GUI's when you can only do stuff through there.